# OpenCV Not Saving Image (imwrite)

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I'm changing the dimensions and save the new image

```
def ResizeImage(filepath, newFileName):
    image = cv2.imread(filepath)
    height, width = image.shape[:2]
    image2 = cv2.resize(image, (width/2, height/2), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    filename = newFileName
    cv2.imwrite(filename,image2)
    return filename
```

When I try open this new file

```
def ShowImage(filepath):
    image = cv2.imread(filepath)
    if image is None:
        print "Cant Load Image"
    else:
        print "Showing {}".format(filepath)
        cv2.imshow("Image", image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

It opens the old file but no the new one (Not saved)

Already try saving new image as bmp, png, jpg and none has worked

Im calling them from here

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    DirPath = ".\PythonScripts\QRReader"
    filename = "HD_qr_example.jpg"
    newfile = ResizeImage(DirPath+"\{}".format(filename),"thumbnail.jpg")
    ShowImage(DirPath+"\{}".format(filename))
    ShowImage(newfile)
```

It only fails on the second ShowImage

Comment: are you missing a comma between the arguments in ResizeImage? I know this is not a solution, but I'm a bit confused

Comment: What does cv2.imwrite() [return](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce)? Likely a permissions issue

Comment: Added coma in Resize, my mistake writing it here

Comment: cv2.imwrite() returns True

Comment: Also checkin current working directory and original path of Image, and none has the new image

Comment: I cannot find an error in the code. Can you please post the ResizeImage() function call block. or the input to the filepath and the newimagename

Comment: @janu777 added to question :)

Comment: You are not passing the second argument to the ResizeImage() function. newFileName?

Comment: @janu777 my bad (writing just here)

Im trying reinstalling the packages

Comment: Can you try altering the path of the new image to have the same path as the original image